# Show Decimal Keyboard in HTML5 iOS 7 / iOS 8

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css, cordova

I just have a simple question after having searched for hours now: Is there any possibility to show the decimal keyboard in webbrowsers input fields? `input type="number"` only shows numbers but i need a comma or dot instead in the bottom left corner.

I tried anything, `pattern`, `step` etc., but nothing brings up the decimal keyboard. I only need the numbers and a dot or comma, no A-Z or a-z or anything else.

```
<input type="number" id="inputNumbers" pattern="[0-9]*" size="30" min="1" max="5">
```

**This is what i get:**
[image]

**This is what i want:**
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checkout `inputmode="decimal"` starting on iOS 12.2

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode

Answer (score 4):

This works for iPhone and Android:

```
<input type="text" inputmode="decimal">
```

Results in this keypad with iPhone 10:

[image: iPhone 10 Decimal Keypad]

And with Android:

[image: Android Decimal Keypad]

Comment: Just as a note, if using React or similar, you may need to call this inputMode instead of inputmode.

Answer (score 3):

> https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard

Lets you configure the decimal character(instead of `.` you can change to `,` )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Or:

```
<input type="tel" />
```

This is a bit of a hack:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

Might work depending on what you are trying to achieve when it comes to input values

This link might be useful:
[Force iOS numeric keyboard with custom / currency pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684855/force-ios-numeric-keyboard-with-custom-currency-pattern)

Hope you come right!

Comment: Have you had a look at the link?

Comment: of course i did. Doesn't work, shows the numeric keyboard without dot or comma.

Comment: none of this worked for me. I ended with a not-so-ugly solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447668/input-type-number-is-not-showing-a-number-keypad-on-ios/48933150#48933150

Answer (score -4):

Check this html code according to your pattern

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[a-z]*">
```